# User can't rate/review my application on Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

A user just complained over email about not being able to post a review/rating on my application on Play Store.

Here's what I know:

- I published the app to production on 12 Dec
- I had the app in open beta on the play store before 12th
- I disabled open beta by clicking "Remove Testers" button on the beta dashboard
- Play console says the beta is shadowed by production
- Said user was a beta user before the app went into production
- Said user posted a beta feedback before the app went into production
- Said user is on the latest version of the app now

I can try to ask for more information from the user but don't want to bug him again and again so is there something I could ask that would be of help?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like the user has beta version, so ask him to uninstall/install

Comment: The user is no longer in beta now, he/she's on the latest version as I said.
I already have asked him/her to reinstall but awaiting a reply.
Sadly, I've most probably lost a good 5-Star rating since the said user was really happy with the application and support.

Comment: @SirBarksalot Have you found a solution? I'm also having the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so even **I was looking to rate one such app which I joined as a beta user**, but couldn't find any option in the (current) mobile version of Play Store.

Neither could we find any option to get out of the beta program, anywhere (like in the app details that was told on support page of Google Play -" Tip: You can [leave a beta program](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7003180#Leave) if you want to write a review. ")

***Solution:*** I went to the web version/desktop version of Google Play (through my laptop), found the app there and voila... I was able to rate and write a review. (Without any beta user hassle)

Hope, that works for your users as well and hopefully Google Play gets fixed soon.

Comment: Been a while since this happened and I don't have anymore beta users. But your answer could help someone else.